# Adding a new scope to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My goal is to create a scope which can only be accessed by users with a certain `role`, in this case "editor". Or rather by admins and editors.

I'm using devise. Here's a part of my attempt:

```
scope "/editor" do
  devise_for :editors

  # ...other routes
end
```

When running it via "rails server":

```
/home/user123/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Editor (NameError)
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding use of the `scope` argument. If you want to restrict access in a certain view you can do the following. Assume you have a video streaming service where a regular user can only access the index and show actions/views, yet an admin can see the rest (`new` `edit` etc...).

You make a concern (google DRY) at `app/controllers/concerns/` and name it admin.rb

```
module IsAdmin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern  

  def admin?
    return redirect_to videos_new, alert: "Access Denied" unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Now in your videos_controller.rb include the concern we just made and tell the controller in which views you want to use the admin? method.

```
Class VideosController < Applicationcontroller
  include IsAdmin
  before_action :admin?, only: [:new, :edit]
end
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question.